# Return values of an array that are at least 3 times in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, duplicates

I'm having trouble making this so I'm asking it here.
I have an array like this:

```
var myArray = ["hi", "hi", "hi", "ha", "ha", "ho", "hu", "hu", "hu"]
```

What I want is storing the values that occur at least 3 times in a new array. So I should get:

```
var filteredArray = ["hi", "hu"]
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: _"What I want is **storing** the values"_ its not sorting its filtering

Comment: do you want a single item of three or more or all item whos count is three or more?

Comment: @NinaScholz Single item in a new array of the items that occur 3 times in the first array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in following steps:

- Create a function which takes an array and least no of times the element should repeat as argument.
- Remove the duplicates from the array using `Set`
- Then use `filter()` on that. Inside `filter()` use `filter()` on the original array(with duplicate values) to get the array of same values.
- Compare the length of that array with the count(second parameter)

```js
var myArray = ["hi", "hi", "hi", "ha", "ha", "ho", "hu", "hu", "hu"];

const valWhichRepeat = (arr,count) => 
                 [...new Set(arr)].filter(x => 
                      arr.filter(a => a === x).length >= count 
                 );

console.log(valWhichRepeat(myArray,3))
```

The above code don't have linear time complexity. If you want liner time complexity you can use `reduce()`to build an object with count of elements and then use `filter()` on its keys.

```js
var myArray = ["hi", "hi", "hi", "ha", "ha", "ho", "hu", "hu", "hu"];

const valWhichRepeat = (arr,count) => {
  const obj = arr.reduce((ac,a) => (ac[a] = ac[a] + 1 || 1,ac),{});
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(x => obj[x] >= count);
}
console.log(valWhichRepeat(myArray,3))
```

The above still uses two loops. If you want to use only a single loop then you can `push()` the elements inside `reduce()`

```js
var myArray = ["hi", "hi", "hi", "ha", "ha", "ho", "hu", "hu", "hu"];

const valWhichRepeat = (arr,count) => 
  arr.reduce(([obj,res],a) => {
    obj[a] = obj[a] + 1 || 1;
    if(obj[a] === count) res.push(a);
    return [obj,res]
  },[{},[]])[1]

console.log(valWhichRepeat(myArray,3))
```

Comment: You can upvote it :) and you can also mark this as correct answer, total giving @Maheer Ali 25 repo point

Comment: @NinaScholz That's true but the time complexity will still be said linear I guess. I have added a method using single loop. However your solution is better and VALZ even more better.

Answer (score 7):

You can do a `.filter` without needing extra variables by using the [optional second parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Parameters) which assigns the `this` context of the callback. So, you can leverage it to keep a count of everything you've encountered and only allow items with a count of 3.

```js
var myArray = ["hi", "hi", "hi", "ha", "ha", "ho", "hu", "hu", "hu"]

var filteredArray = myArray.filter(item => {
  //check what the count so far is
  var count = this[item] ? this[item] : 0;
  //add one and assign it back as the new count
  this[item] = ++count;
  
  //only return the item if the count is 3
  return count === 3;
 }, {})
 
console.log(filteredArray)
```

For a more concise implementation, you can use the one suggested by @georg

```js
var myArray = ["hi", "hi", "hi", "ha", "ha", "ho", "hu", "hu", "hu"]

var filteredArray = myArray.filter(item => (this[item] = ++this[item] || 1) === 3, {})
 
console.log(filteredArray)
```

Comment: Good idea, you could also golf the func to `(this[item] = ++this[item] || 1) === 3`

Comment: @georg I was striving for clarity, but you're right. I did actually start off with something similar but then expanded :)

Comment: I like the readable version more, you know why when you need to work with others.

Answer (score 5):

You could take a hash table and count the occurences. Then filter if the count is three.

This approach works with a single loop: **O(n)**

```js
var array = ["hi", "hi", "hi", "ha", "ha", "ho", "hu", "hu", "hu"],
    hash = {},
    result = array.filter(v => (hash[v] = (hash[v] || 0) + 1) === 3);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Object.entries(myArray.reduce((res, cur) => {
    res[cur] = (res[cur] || 0) + 1
    return res
}, {})).filter(([k, v]) => v >= 3).map(([k, v]) => k)
```

Comment: Could you comment a little bit your answer?

Comment: After reduce, return a map (key: string in myArray, value: the total count)
Object.entries  will iterate the map, and return an array.
And filter will find the filt the correct value.
And map will return the data structure you need.

Comment: I guess it should be `(res[cur] || 0) + 1`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myArray = ["hi", "hi", "hi", "ha", "ha", "ho", "hu", "hu", "hu"]
var temp = {}
var filteredArray = []
for(let i = 0;i < myArray.length;i++){
    if(temp[myArray[i]]){
        temp[myArray[i]] += 1
    }else{
        temp[myArray[i]] = 1
    }
}
for(let key in temp){
    if(temp[key] >= 3){
        filteredArray.push(key)
    }
}

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function count() {
    array_elements = ["hi", "hi", "hi", "ha", "ha", "ho", "hu", "hu", "hu"];
    var filteredArray = [];
    var current = null;
    var cnt = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array_elements.length; i++) {
        if (array_elements[i] != current) {
            if (cnt >= 3) {
              filteredArray.push(current);
            }
            current = array_elements[i];
            cnt = 1;
        } else {
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    if (cnt >= 3) {
      filteredArray.push(current);
    }
  document.write(filteredArray);
}
count()
```

Comment: This results in `hi` only